# Titanium Textfield on TableView not getting focused

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I am having few text fields inside the table view, while clicking on the text fields it is not getting focused(in Android platform). I have seen some [questions](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117540/textfield-on-tableview-loses-focus-android) regarding the same issue, but those suggestions not worked for me. I am using Titanium 1.7.5, Android 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and some steps you should keep in mind:

- Don't add a `focus` event to the field, this will overwrite the build-in one
- Add the event `singletap` and fire the `focus` event on that field

`mytextfield.addEventListener('singletap',function(){ mytextfield.focus(); });`

This should do the trick, at least, it did for me.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem in Android to set the Edit Text Property:

android:imeOptions="actionSearch"

If it is not working on Mobile Device, I have another solution for it:

android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"

Comment: How to set `android:imeOptions` in Alloy. I always fail to compile if adding it in `<TextField>`.

Answer (score 0):

textfields did not act identically on every device while gaining the focus. you should have a look at the [softKeyboardOnFocus](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TextField.softKeyboardOnFocus-property.html)-property. it can have the following value:

```
Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEFAULT_ON_FOCUS
Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_HIDE_ON_FOCUS
Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS
```

maybe it helps to set the property to SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS. this requests to show soft keyboard on focus. keep in mind that android can override this.